# Using ggplot2 & geom_bar to change bar color based on 1 factor variable and bar pattern based on another factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, apple-m1

I want to use ggplot2 & geom_bar to change bar color based on 1 factor variable and bar pattern based on another factor variable.

I can't figure out how to do this.

I use a Macbook Pro with Apple silicon, running R version 4.1.3 and RStudio 2022.02.1.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use [ggpattern](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggpattern) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpattern)

tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~fill, ~pattern,
  "a", 10, 1, 3,
  "a", 15, 1, 3,
  "a", 20, 1, 2,
  "b", 10, 0, 2,
  "b", 12, 0, 3,
  "b", 13, 0, 3
) |> 
  mutate(fill = factor(fill),
         pattern = factor(pattern)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(aes(pattern = pattern), stat = "identity", 
                   pattern_colour = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This works really well. The only issue that I have is that when I use it on my data (not your example data), I cannot get the x and y variables to change position to a horizontal bar plot using the coord_flip command (I get this error: "Error in seq.default(from, to, by) : invalid '(to - from)/by'"). If you have an idea of what going on, please lmk, although you've already done plenty. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mel are you able to share a minimal reproducible example with a little of your data that produces the error?

Comment: I'll try to do so, but I think the issue stems from my grouping variables not being numeric in nature. When I change it to numeric form, I don't get that issue. I do want to have different colors for different levels, but the ggpattern package seems to want to use color gradients rather than distinct colors.